# symfony change locale in route during login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, routes, locale

I'm stumbling upon an issue on changing the locale during the login event on a symfony (2.7) application. I was following the sticky locale symfony article http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html, but not using the session at all.

I'm using the approach that every URI contains one representation only. Therefore all routes contain the {_locale} (and no need of a session variable for sticky locales).

I'm just using the UserLocaleListener part to get the users locale and tried to set it into the route like on this github issue https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/829.

My problem possibly is, that on login is already a URI locale set. During the login event, I need/want to overwrite this locale value. As mentioned by the github article, I added the *router context*.

UserLocaleListener InteractiveLoginEvent

```
/**
 * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
 */
public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
    $locale = $user->getLocale();

    if (null !== $locale) {
        $request->setLocale($locale);
        $this->router->getContext()->setParameter('_locale', $locale);

        //var_dump(); die;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work (at least on my symfony 2.7).

If I dump the requests locale or the router context locale, the correct user locale was applied to the context, but not changed/applied on redirecting to the *default_target_path* or any other path.

Is the *onInteractiveLoginEvent* already too late to change the locale in an URI? Or how do I best change the locale in the URI during a (form based) login?

Many thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

as i explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892440/soanta-admin-bundle-locale/32904386#32904386)

the locale is set on the request, and will not "stick" , so each request it will be the default again, unless you do something like this:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, unfortunately it's not the key point here. As I pointed out, the solution is already built on the symfony article you mentioned.

Differnt to the symfony article is, that every URI already contains the locale (it does not come from session).

The issue is, the locale is already in the URI, and on login, this locale needs to be overwritten. But I'm not able to overwrite the locale in the onInteractiveLogin event.