# Sonata Admin Translations does not work according to locale

Tags: sonata

According to doc - https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/translation.html
I have a list of messages in the way of **label underscore strategy,** inside Resources as
 
    app/Resources/translations/messages.fr.yml
    app/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml

further according to doc - https://sonata-project.org/bundles/translation/master/doc/reference/installation.html

```
# config/packages/sonata.yaml

sonata_translation:
    locales: [en, fr]
    default_locale: en
    gedmo:
        enabled: false
    knplabs:
        enabled: true
```

but somehow the site does not get the right translations according to the browser locale when you click on country flags.
but it just works on *default_locale: en*

any ideas would help me a lot :)

Comment: Actually the question is not totally related to sonata admin (sorry I did not aware of it) but its partially related to symfony basic config **default_locale**
even when I switched to another locale, the system still stick to the default_locale

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I found the answer here,
[Soanta Admin Bundle Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892440/soanta-admin-bundle-locale).
Thanks *sam-janssens*
 I have used the symfony doc -
http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/session/locale_sticky_session.html, 
and it works for me.

if any one need of any details do not hesitate to leave a comment.